# Do you need to save a file locally before sending it to a mongo db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, multer

I am learning how to upload images from my React website to my Mongo database through an express server. In every tutorial I have read, the author saves the file locally in the express server before sending it to the Mongo database. Is there a way to avoid having to store the file locally by keeping it in a local variable which is then uploaded to the database?

Here are the tutorials I am referring to:

https://www.positronx.io/react-file-upload-tutorial-with-node-express-and-multer/

https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess The GridFS API would be helpful to you.It says :

> you can .pipe() directly from file streams to MongoDB

Here is the sample example according to doc :

```
const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require('fs');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'test';

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(error, client) {
  assert.ifError(error);

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db);

  fs.createReadStream('./meistersinger.mp3').
    pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('meistersinger.mp3')).
    on('error', function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
    }).
    on('finish', function() {
      console.log('done!');
      process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

documentation link : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/gridfs/streaming/

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

yes you want to store you files locally. I used an NFS server (FreeNas) and mounted it to that local folder.

So when i saved a file to that location, it was stored on the other NFS server. Then i sent that image location as a response back to react, which then saved that location in Mongodb.

Example uploads.js

```
router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    let CurrentDate = moment().unix();
    if (req.files.file === null) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'no file uploaded' });
    }

    let user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    let file = req.files.file;

    file.name = CurrentDate + user._id + '.jpg';


    file.mv(`./client/public/uploads/${file.name}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }


        res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}`});
    });
});
```

This is what the mongodb entry looks like

```
image:"/uploads/15951066675f1365239d46882312332d20.jpg"
```